# Rational guessing of a chosen number in a given range

Tags: python

There is task:

> The player picks a random number between 1 and 100 that the computer has to guess. Before you start, think about how you guess. If all goes well, try coding the game.

My code is:

```
import random
num = int(input('Your number: '))
numC = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 1
while numC != num:
    numC = random.randint(1, 100)
    if numC > num:
        print(numC, 'Less')
        numC = random.randint(1, numC)
    else:
        print(numC, 'More')
        numC = random.randint(numC, 100)
    tries += 1
print(numC, 'Computer guessed your number with', tries, 'tries')
```

It works, but I don't think it works as the author wanted.

How to make this program guess number using fewers tries? I know that it's about decreasing frames of random generator, but I don't know how to do this without using infinite number of variables.

Comment: Use binary partitioning! Instead of picking a *random* number in the ranges `1..numC` or `numC..100`, try the one exactly in the middle. In particular, the line `numC = random.randint(1, 100)` should *not* be inside this loop.

Comment: have you heard about binary search? try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change that way, to remember the range dynamically and guess in the correct range

```
import random
num = int(input('Your number: '))
numC = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 1
lowerLimit=1
upperLimit=100
while numC != num:
  if numC > num:
    print(numC, 'Less')
    upperLimit = numC+1
  else:
    print(numC, 'More')
    lowerLimit = numC-1
  tries += 1
  numC = random.randint(lowerLimit, upperLimit)
print(numC, 'Computer guessed your number with', tries, 'tries')
```

Comment: `upperLimit = numC - 1` and `lwoerLimit = numC + 1`

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, what do you think about this?

```
import random
num = int(input('Your number: '))
tries = []
numC = random.randint(1, 100)
while numC != num:
    numC = random.randint(1, 100)
    if numC in tries:
        pass
    elif numC > num:
        print(numC, 'Less')
        tries.append(numC)
    elif numC < num:
        print(numC, 'More')
        tries.append(numC)
print(numC, 'Computer guessed your number with', len(tries), 'tries')
```

Comment: Why do you use `tries` list?

Comment: @Alex.S Well, I thought that put all numbers that have tried in a list, then when try a new number, check the list first if it has been tried. But however Bruce's answer is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but my program can only guess if the user tells the computer whether the Computer's guess is higher or lower than the User's number. I also added all sorts of other stuff to make it more User-Friendly. Here it is anyway:

`def bp(x):
        if '.' in str(x):
            tenth=int(str(x).split('.')[1][0])
            if tenth<=4:
                return str(x).split('.')[0]
            else:
                return int(str(x).split('.')[0])+1
        else:
            return x
        guess=50
        low=0
        high=100
        rep=0
        while rep<=10:
                        try:
                                reply=input('Is the number %s? (Y/H/L)\n'%guess)
                        except IndexError:
                                continue
                        if reply=='y':
                                print('Haha!')
                                break
                        elif reply=='l':
                                low=guess
                        elif reply=='h':
                                high=guess
                        else:
                                print("Enter 'Yes', 'Low', or 'High'")
                                continue
                        rep+=1
                        guess=bp((int(low)+int(high))/2)
                        break`

Answer (score 0):

What about avoiding to guess a number in a specific range.
Just use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) as the comments tell and start with guessing 50.

```
import random

num = int(input('Your number: '))
tries = 1
lowerLimit = 1
upperLimit = 100
numC = 50

while numC != num:
    if numC > num:
        print(numC, 'Less')
        upperLimit = numC
    else:
        print(numC, 'More')
        lowerLimit = numC
    tries += 1
    numC = lowerLimit + (upperLimit - lowerLimit) / 2

print(numC, 'Computer guessed your number with', tries, 'tries')
```

You can expect a worst case runtime of 7 tries.

[image: runtime]

Comment: @AntonL What do you think about this solution?